# MPI Gathering columns into bigger matrix

Tags: matrix, mpi, openmpi

Lets say I 3 different matrix on 3 different threads:

```
a1 a2       a3 a4       a5 a6
b1 b2       b3 b4       b5 b6
c1 c2       c3 c4       c5 c6
d1 d2       d3 d4       d5 d6
e1 e2       e3 e4       e5 e6
f1 f2       f3 f4       f5 f6
```

I want to gather them by using MPI_Gather into this one matrix

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
```

I am using

```
MPI_Gather(&oldMatrix,N/size,columnType,&newMatrix,N/size,gatherColType,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Where coltype is:

```
 MPI_Type_vector(N,    
               1,                  
               N/size,         
               MPI_FLOAT,       
                 &column);
 MPI_Type_commit(&column);
 MPI_Type_create_resized(column, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &columnType);
 MPI_Type_commit(&columnType);
```

However, I am not sure how should i create gatherColType (if it is needed). Can you help me about that?

note: N is matrix size and size is thread count (i.e. 3 in this question)

Comment: why do you think `columnType` is not a good fit for the receive datatype ?

Comment: Because i did not get correct result by setting columnType as receive type.

Comment: there could be something wrong in the way you declared the matrices. can you please create and upload a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then i will have a look at it ?

Comment: you might try to keep a stride of `N/size` for `columnType`, but use a stride of `N` for gatherColType.